# Difference between PrincipalSearcher and DirectorySearcher

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I see Active Directory examples that use `PrincipalSearcher` and other examples that do the same thing but use `DirectorySearcher`. What is the difference between these two examples?

Example using `PrincipalSearcher`

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context));
foreach( UserPrincipal user in search.FindAll() )
{
    if( null != user )
        Console.WriteLine(user.DistinguishedName);
}
```

Example using `DirectorySearcher`

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher("(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))");
search.PageSize = 1000;
foreach( SearchResult result in search.FindAll() )
{
    DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
    if( null != user )
        Console.WriteLine(user.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: For me it would be the strong typing?, better abstraction. Doesn't the Principal Searcher live in the an Active Directory management extensions library or some such. The more the commmunity know of this the better. I used it to avoid the gnarly syntax usually encountered when messing with AD.

Comment: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement is the library fwiw.

Comment: +1 Nice code samples! See my answer maybe it'll help answer this question

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I've spent a lot of time analyzing the differences between these two. Here's what I've learned.

- `DirectorySearcher` comes from the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace.
- `PrincipalSearcher` comes from the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace, which is built on top of `System.DirectoryServices`. `PrincipalSearcher` internally uses `DirectorySearcher`.
- The `AccountManagement` namespace (i.e. `PrincipalSearcher`) was designed to simplify management of User, Group, and Computer objects (i.e. Principals). In theory, it's usage should be easier to understand, and produce fewer lines of code. Though in my practice so far, it seems to heavily depend on what you're doing.
- `DirectorySearcher` is more low-level and can deal with more than just User, Group and Computer objects.
- For general usage, when you're working with basic attributes and only a few objects,  `PrincipalSearcher` will result in fewer lines of code and faster run time.
- The advantage seems to disappear the more advanced the tasks you're doing become. For instance if you're expecting more than few hundred results, you'll have to get the underlying `DirectorySearcher` and set the `PageSize`

  ```
  DirectorySearcher ds = search.GetUnderlyingSearcher() as DirectorySearcher;
  if( ds != null )
      ds.PageSize = 1000;
  ```
- `DirectorySearcher` can be significantly faster than `PrincipalSearcher` if you make use of `PropertiesToLoad`.
- `DirectorySearcher` and like classes can work with all objects in AD, whereas `PrincipalSearcher` is much more limited. For example, you can not modify an Organizational Unit using `PrincipalSearcher` and like classes.

Here is a chart I made to analyze using `PrincipalSearcher`, `DirectorySearcher` without using `PropertiesToLoad`, and `DirectorySearcher` with using `PropertiesToLoad`. All tests...

- Use a `PageSize` of `1000`
- Query a total of 4,278 user objects
- Specify the following criteria

  - `objectClass=user`
  - `objectCategory=person`
  - Not a scheduling resource (i.e. `!msExchResourceMetaData=ResourceType:Room`)
  - Enabled (i.e. `!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2`)

[image: DirectorySearcher vs. PrincipalSearcher Performance Chart]

#### Code For Each Test

---

**Using `PrincipalSearcher`**

```
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("Person")]
public class UserPrincipalEx: UserPrincipal
{

    private AdvancedFiltersEx _advancedFilters;

    public UserPrincipalEx( PrincipalContext context ): base(context)
    {
        this.ExtensionSet("objectCategory","User");
    }

    public new AdvancedFiltersEx AdvancedSearchFilter
    {
        get {
            if( null == _advancedFilters )
                _advancedFilters = new AdvancedFiltersEx(this);
                return _advancedFilters;
        }
    }

}

public class AdvancedFiltersEx: AdvancedFilters 
{

    public AdvancedFiltersEx( Principal principal ): 
        base(principal) { }

    public void Person()
    {
        this.AdvancedFilterSet("objectCategory", "person", typeof(string), MatchType.Equals);
        this.AdvancedFilterSet("msExchResourceMetaData", "ResourceType:Room", typeof(string), MatchType.NotEquals);
    }
}

//...

for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    uint count = 0;
    Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    UserPrincipalEx filter = new UserPrincipalEx(context);
    filter.Enabled = true;
    filter.AdvancedSearchFilter.Person();
    PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(filter);
    DirectorySearcher ds = search.GetUnderlyingSearcher() as DirectorySearcher;
    if( ds != null )
        ds.PageSize = 1000;
    foreach( UserPrincipalEx result in search.FindAll() )
    {
        string canonicalName = result.CanonicalName;
        count++;
    }

    timer.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1} ms", count, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

**Using `DirectorySearcher`**

```
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    uint count = 0;
    string queryString = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(!msExchResourceMetaData=ResourceType:Room)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))";

    Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry();
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry,queryString);
    search.PageSize = 1000;
    foreach( SearchResult result in search.FindAll() )
    {
        DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
        if( user != null )
        {
            user.RefreshCache(new string[]{"canonicalName"});
            string canonicalName = user.Properties["canonicalName"].Value.ToString();
            count++;
        }
    }
    timer.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1} ms", count, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

**Using `DirectorySearcher` with `PropertiesToLoad`**

Same as "Using `DirectorySearcher` but add this line

```
search.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new string[] { "canonicalName" });
```

After

```
search.PageSize = 1000;
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Whilst the directorysearch was quicker than the principal search I found that subsequent searches were quicker with the principalsearcher. I'm guessing there is come sort of caching under the hood.

Comment: What is UserPrincipalEx?

Comment: It's extension of `UserPrinciple` that makes use of the `AdvancedFiltersEx` class so that it can filter out based `msExchResourceMetaData` and `objectCategory`.

Comment: If I remember I'll post the code for it later. But it's really simple and can be find in other posts if you want to see it before I post it.

Comment: @druciferre another difference is that you can specify the domain controller using PrincipalSearcher, but you can't if you use DirectorySearcher.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave, this is not accurate. You can specify it at minimum using an LDAP search root (e.g. `new DirectorySearcher("LDAP://domaincontrollername/DC=contoso,DC=local")`. There is another way too given just the DC name or to list all of the DCs. I have a code sample I can post later when I get back to my PC. I had to write a block of code to get the most accurate login time from all DCs.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave, see my Gist for an [example of using a specific DC](https://gist.github.com/druciferre/8cdd93bbf45faa54c90cbc6cf57bbc07).

Comment: I changed my Gist/GitHub username. New link for [example of using a specific DC](https://gist.github.com/drewchapin/8cdd93bbf45faa54c90cbc6cf57bbc07)

Comment: What about if you use PrincipalSearcher but using GetUnderlyingSearcher add in the PropertiesToLoad? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357892/why-is-directorysearcher-so-slow-when-compared-to-principalsearcher

Comment: I want to retrieve attribute msExchRecipientDisplayType and  PrincipalSearcher gives System.__ComObject. as a result it gives proper value by DirectorySearcher. but DirectorySearcher has only 1000 limit ??

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62306314/why-principalsearcher-gives-system-comobject-for-attribut-msexchrecipientdispl

Comment: Why does your `UserPrincipleEx` set `objectCategory` to `User` with `ExtensionSet` but your `AdvancedFilterSet` tests for `objectCategory` equal to `person`?

Comment: Major issue in your code is that you're not disposing of your objects but you didn't do it with either example so I'm not sure how that would influence your results, especially doing this in a loop.  I do like your extension method.

Answer (score 5):

`PrincipalSearcher` is used to query the Directory for Groups or Users. `DirectorySearcher` is used to query all kinds of objects.

I used `DirectorySearcher` to get groups before then I discovered `PrincipalSearcher` so when I replaced the former with the latter, the speed of my program improved (maybe it was just `PrincipalSearcher` that created a better query for me. For what I care, `PrincipalSearcher` was just easier to use and more suitable for the task of getting pricipals.

`DirectorySearcher` on the other hand is more general as it can get other kinds of objects. This is why it can't be strongly typed as mentioned in the comments. `PrincipalSearcher` is all about principals so it will have strongly typed objects that pertain to principals, and this is why also you don't need to tell it to get you an object of kind user or group, it will be implied by the Principal classes you use.

Answer (score 1):

DirectorySearcher is by far faster. The example from @DrewChapin can be taken even further. By my tests, about 10 times further/faster. I was able to pull 721 computer cn's in 3.8 seconds with his code. Pretty fast. With my changes I did it in 0.38 seconds. Depending on what you're doing, this could be huge. I used this in a predictive account search (Start typing the name and a combobox populates. A very short System.Timer starts after each keypress and is cancelled by a keypress. If the timer elapses, the list updates. Efficiency is huge for this.)

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry();
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry,queryString);
search.PageSize = 1000;
// *** Added following line
search.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new string[] { "canonicalName" });
foreach( SearchResult result in search.FindAll() )
{
    //DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
    // *** Work directly with result instead of user
    if( result != null )
    {
        //user.RefreshCache(new string[]{"canonicalName"});
        // *** Following line modified
        string canonicalName = result.Properties["canonicalName"][0].ToString();
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: AuthenticationTypes.FastBind increases the performance quite a bit for DirectorySearcher.  Also look at your ReferralChasingOptions.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that has made my PrincipalSearcher queries much faster than before is to use this syntax.  I convert it to a Queryable after returning FindAll().  I'm returning 3000 records in about 2 seconds.  I also run this in an async method.

```
using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainname", 
  "DOMAIN_DESCRIPTOR"))
{
    using (var u = new UserPrincipal(ctx))
    {
          var result = new PrincipalSearcher(u)
                        .FindAll()
                        .AsQueryable()
                        .Take(3000)
```