# Active Directory : PropertiesToLoad get all properties

Tags: c#, active-directory

I try to get a List of all properties from an Object in the Active Directory.

What I have for now is this:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
try
{
    DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");
    root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + root.Properties["defaultNamingContext"][0]);
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(root);
    search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";

    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("title");

    SearchResultCollection results = search.FindAll();
    if (results != null)
    {
        foreach (SearchResult result in results)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry property in result.Properties)
            {
                Debug.Write(property.Key + ": ");
                foreach (var val in (property.Value as ResultPropertyValueCollection)) { 
                    Debug.Write(val +"; ");
                }
                Debug.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

But it gets only the properties I added with PropertiesToLoad. Is it possible to get all properties dynamically?

Comment: If you check out drew chapins answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176284/difference-between-principalsearcher-and-directorysearcher 
You will know WHY you want to limit by propertiestoLoad. VeryFast vs VerySlow you make the call ..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't specify anything in `PropertiesToLoad`, you should get all the properties. Just remove the lines with `search.PropertiesToLoad.Add`.

Getting all the properties of all the users in the domain could be pretty heavy, however.

Comment: omg i tried it with PropertiesToLoad.Add(String.Empty), but I didn't expect it would be that simple. Thanks

Comment: This is super-late, but please *don't* return all the user properties. It's that kind of badly-constructed search that taxes AD. Given the fact that AD will include internal attributes that only make sense to Exchange, Skype etc, returning *all* gives a load of cruft that you'll never use.

Comment: There are hundreds of properties, to load properties that not return by default, check the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/attributes-all and add to load list.

Comment: @trix If you check out drew chapins answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176284/difference-between-principalsearcher-and-directorysearcher 
You will know WHY you want to limit by propertiestoLoad. VeryFast vs VerySlow you make the call ..

Comment: @Ken, I don't know whether you were meaning to address someone else, but I clearly stated *not* to return all properties. The comment at the start of the thread suggests *not* specifying `PropertiesToLoad` and I disagreed with that suggestion.

Comment: @feargood If you check out drew chapins answer here : stackoverflow.com/questions/23176284/… You will know WHY you want to limit by propertiestoLoad. VeryFast vs VerySlow you make the call

Comment: @Trix yes .. meant for someone else - you were correct in your comment. When requesting data better to filter for what you want in the request and not after the request. Why ask for a boat load of wrenches when you simply need the one. Lots of overhead..

Answer (score 1):

To get all propertyNames you can do:

```
 SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
 ResultPropertyCollection temp = result.Properties;

 string[] propertyNamesList = new string[temp.PropertyNames.Count];
 temp.PropertyNames.CopyTo(propertyNamesList, 0);
```

and propertyNamesList will contain everything there.