# Why is DirectorySearcher so slow when compared to PrincipalSearcher?

Tags: c#, active-directory

Our application has a process which fetches all users from Active Directory and updates the relevant SQL tables with their information. The process at nights and it was written a few years ago - so it's legacy code which works and "if it ain't broken, don't fix it". However we're introducing a new feature to our application which requires modifications to this code, and since it hasn't been touched for years I thought I might as well clean it up a little.

Said process runs ONLY during the night except for rare server faults, in which case we have to run it manually during the day. The process uses the good old `System.DirectoryServices` library to do its job, and although it works, it runs quite slowly.

I thought about using the newer `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` library instead, so I started rewriting the whole process (a few hundreds lines of code) and I was amazed to see that `PrincipalSearcher` **dramatically** outperforms `DirectorySearcher`.

I've been trying to look for the reason and came upon [the following SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26321067/4183902) which gives a comparison between the two, stating that `DirectorySearcher` should be faster than `PrincipalSearcher`.

I fired up a test project to make sure I was not hallucinating:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // New stuff
        var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com");
        var properties = new[] { "cn", "name", "distinguishedname", "surname", "title", "displayname" };
        var i = 0;
        var now = DateTime.Now;

        new Thread(delegate()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("\r{0} ms, {1} results", (DateTime.Now - now).TotalMilliseconds, i);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }).Start();

        using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
        {
            var underlying = searcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher() as DirectorySearcher;
            underlying.PageSize = 1000;
            underlying.PropertiesToLoad.Clear();
            underlying.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(properties);
            underlying.CacheResults = false;

            using (var results = searcher.FindAll())
            {
                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("It took {0}", (DateTime.Now - now).TotalMilliseconds);
        now = DateTime.Now;
        i = 0;

        // Old stuff
        var root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=mydomain,DC=com");
        var filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user))";

        using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root, filter, properties))
        {
            searcher.PageSize = 1000;
            searcher.CacheResults = false;

            using (var results = searcher.FindAll())
            {
                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("It took {0}", (DateTime.Now - now).TotalMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Querying some thousand users, the results were around 0.9ms per user with `PrincipalSearcher` (around 30 seconds for ~34k users) and around 5.2ms per user with `DirectorySearcher` (around 2 minutes and 30 seconds for ~34k users) - `PrincipalSearcher` being almost six times faster.

I tried debugging and comparing the `PrincipalSearcher`'s underlying `DirectorySearcher` with the one I created and they seemed pretty much similar.

I tried examining further ahead and it seems that if I use the search root from the `PrincipalSearcher`'s underlying searcher, then the `DirectorySearcher` I create actually outperforms the `PrincipalSearcher`:

```
        // ...

        DirectoryEntry psRoot;

        using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
        {
            var underlying = searcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher() as DirectorySearcher;
            psRoot = underlying.SearchRoot;

            // ...
        }

        // ...

        using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(psRoot, filter, properties))
        {
            // ...
        }
```

While debugging I found out that the search roots are largely the same - i.e., they represent the same domain.

What could cause the search speed to slow down like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While writing this question I was tinkering with the test code and managed to find the issue. By providing the domain address when constructing the root `DirectoryEntry`:

```
// var root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=mydomain,DC=com");
var root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://mydomain.com/DC=mydomain,DC=com");
```

The search with `DirectorySearcher` outperformed that of `PrincipalSearcher`. I'm not exactly sure why - perhaps it's something to do with where the searcher looks for the results - but it definitely boosted the search speed.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [my question and answer on the differences between the two methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176284/difference-between-principalsearcher-and-directorysearcher/26321067#26321067). `PrincipalSearcher` is merely a wrapper around `DirectorySearcher`. It was designed to make it easier to work with Active Directory while providing some automated speed enhancements. `DirectorySearcher` can be much faster than `PrincipalSearcher`, but it requires a bit more work.

The main reason you're seeing slow behavior from your "old stuff" code is that in when you used `PrincipalSearcher` in "new stuff", you got the underlying `DirectorySearcher` and fed its `PropertiesToLoad` collection. You did not do that in your "old stuff" code.

```
var properties = new[] { "cn", "name", "distinguishedname", "surname", "title", "displayname" };
//...
var underlying = searcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher() as DirectorySearcher;
//...
underlying.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(properties);
```

As a result, your "old stuff" code was pulling every AD attribute for matched results (i.e. significantly more data being transferred), while your implementation using `PrincipalSearcher` was only reading 6 attributes.

Doing that when using `PrincipalSearcher` is also generally not necessary as it handles caching and picking of attributes on its own. Really, when working with `PrincipalSearcher` the only time you need to get the underlying `DirectorySearcher` is to set the `PageSize` since `PrincipalSearcher` doesn't provide a standard way to set it.

I suspect the reason you saw an improvement when specifying the domain is that it didn't have to do any work to figure out the domain name. You unfairly give "new stuff" a head start in that regards because you made the `PrincipalContext` before you started the clock so to speak.

```
// New stuff
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com");
var properties = new[] { "cn", "name", "distinguishedname", "surname", "title", "displayname" };
var i = 0;
var now = DateTime.Now; // you should have done this BEFORE setting `context`.
```

Some other things I noticed in your code that would actually skew the timing in the opposite direction is that in "new stuff", you don't do any filtering, and the initialization of your delegated thread to show the progress occurs AFTER you recorded the start time.