# Why PrincipalSearcher gives System.__ComObject for attribut msExchRecipientDisplayType?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices, comobject

Why PrincipalSearcher gives System.__ComObject for attribut  msExchRecipientDisplayType ??

I want to retrieve attribute **msExchRecipientDisplayType** and **PrincipalSearcher** gives **System.__ComObject**. Also I tried to retrieve it by **DirectorySearcher** and it gives correct value

i.e. ''.

0  UserMailbox (shared)
1  MailUniversalDistributionGroup
6  MailContact
7  UserMailbox (room)
8  UserMailbox (equipment)
1073741824  UserMailbox
1073741833  MailUniversalSecurityGroup

as mentioned here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_exchon-mso_o365b/recipient-type-values/7c2620e5-9870-48ba-b5c2-7772c739c651

But DirectorySearcher has only 1000 limit ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, I don't know why you're seeing a `System.__ComObject` value for the `msExchRecipientDisplayType` attribute.

About the 1000 result limit: this is a limit from Active Directory, not just `DirectorySearcher`. To get more results, you need to enable paging, which you can do by setting the [`PageSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.pagesize) property of the `DirectorySearcher`. Just set it to `1000` and it will keep making new queries for the next thousand until there are no more. For example,

```
var ds = new DirectorySearcher() {
    Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))",
    PropertiesToLoad = { "msExchRecipientDisplayType" },
    PageSize = 1000
};
```

Comment: Sure I will update code after few hrs. I receiving system.comobject in principle searchr ... But it is fine by directory searcher. But directory searcher has 1000 page limit. So it's not worth.

Comment: To get more than 1000 you just need to set the `PageSize`, like I described in this answer.

Comment: PageSize property of the DirectorySearcher give first 1000 results every time. How it could other results means next results??

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you are using? When I set `PageSize = 1000`, I get thousands of results from my domain, in pages of 1000.